# How do you make real, secure benchmarks?

Tags: language-agnostic, benchmarking

According to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213386/what-are-the-reasons-for-great-performance-differences-running-the-same-program), a benchmark run on the same machine had very varying results.

I'm not asking about how to use `microtime` or whichever framework, but rather, how do you make sure that your benchmarks are not biased in any way? Any machine setup, software setup, process setup? Is there a way to make sure your benchmarks can be safely used as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Basically benchmarking is kind of like a scientific study, so the same rules apply. A benchmark is usually done to answer some kind of question, so start with formulating a good question. After that it is practice and experience to eliminate all the wrong bias.

Make sure you know and document the runtime environment in detail(e.g. switch off power management and other background tasks that might disturb measurements).
Make sure you repeat the experiment (benchmark run) often enough to get good and stable averages and document it.
Make sure you know what you are measuring (e.g. use a working set thats larger than all caches if you want to measure memory performance etc., or using as many threads as you have cores and so on).

In some cases this involves getting caches filled and datasets cached, in other cases you need to do the exact opposite. Depends on the question you want to answer with your benchmark.